# What are Fetch Index Elements in the CoreData Model?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, entity, xcdatamodel

In my xcdatamodel two new fields, `byTitleIndex` and `compoundIndex`, are showing under Fetch Index Elements. I have not seen this section before in Xcode. What is a Fetch Index Element?

[image: Screenshot of Xcode xcdatamodel highlighting compoundIndex field]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386614/ios-cant-compile-coredata-model-because-of-fetched-indexes-in-xcode-9 may be this help

Comment: ... or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922581/3985749).

Comment: Please look at this answer. Explained here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46845344

Comment: I much prefer the given answer below to the links supplied above.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Fetch Index Elements are part of Apple’s new indexing API, announced at WWDC 2017. They allow you to specify one or more Index Elements; properties that are used to create an index for faster database searches. In your case, the "title" property will be used to create an index called “compoundIndex” under your "Passage" entity, allowing for faster title searches.

Announcement:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/210/?time=628

Demo:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/210/?time=997

Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel#2888062