# Core Data - What are the use of "Type" and "Expression" in Fetch Index Elements?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

May I know, what are **Type** and **Expression** ?

[image]

The 2 fields are always being read-only.

May I know what are they used for? Is there any situation where they are editable?

Comment: your question look like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664780/what-are-fetch-index-elements-in-the-coredata-model.

Comment: They are editable if you select "Expression" in the Property field.  You can then choose the type of expression (Integer, String, etc) and enter the expression to be used to calculate the value for the index.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by *@pbasdf* in the comments, the `Type` & `Expression` are editable only when you select `Expression` in the `Property` dropdown.

When you select a known property (like `NSTabInfo.order` in your case), `CoreData` already knows about this property `Type` from data model and `Expression` is not relevant for this case. So they are locked.

When you select `Expression` in the `Property` dropdown, `Type` & `Expression` are editable and you can provide whatever you want.

[image]

Note : Above example is **not tested** / **well formed expression**. To learn about the syntax, you should explore [`NSExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression) api. Here's an [old blog post](https://eezytutorials.com/ios/nsexpression-by-example.php#.YOhdQxOA6S4) to get you started.

Example taken from the blog post (in `Objective-C`)-

```
NSExpression* expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"%d*%f", 3, 3.5];
NSLog(@"%@", [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]);
// 10.5
```